# VB SQL Server Ignoring Default Values

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm using some simple vb code to log a users login to my program. The idea is that the Server uses default values to automatically fill in the time / date columns with the correct time/date. I know I can retrieve both of these from the client computer, but this is reliant on their device being set to the right time and time zone. I can't seem to get the server to use the default value when I use the below code. Both my columns seem to resort to 00:00:00 (for the time one) and 1900:01:01 (for the date column). But when I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to in put fake data it correct defaults to the current time and date.

```
con.open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Account_Login_Log VALUES (@memberID, @accountID, @logintime, @logindate)", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", "32")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountID", "91")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logintime", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logindate", "")

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.close()
```

My question is, why isn't my code automatically defaulting at the server end to the correct time and date?

*I have tried:*

Omitting the columns from my insert statement, using the dbNULL.value and also simply specifying "" as I have shown in my code above. But all resort to the beginning of time.

**Edit** - I have included my complete table definitions below.

```
USE [Atlas]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Account_Login_Log]    Script Date: 26/01/2015 8:34:21 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account_Login_Log](
    [lLogID] [int] IDENTITY(10,1) NOT NULL,
    [lMember_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [lAccount_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [lLogin_Time] [time](7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_Login_Log_lLogin_Time]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([varchar](8),getdate(),(108))),
    [lLogin_Date] [date] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_Login_Log_lLogin_Date]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Account_Login_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [lLogID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account_Login_Log]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_Login_Log_Account1] FOREIGN KEY([lAccount_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Account] ([aAccount_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account_Login_Log] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_Login_Log_Account1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account_Login_Log]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_Login_Log_Member_Details] FOREIGN KEY([lMember_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Member_Details] ([mMember_ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account_Login_Log] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_Login_Log_Member_Details]
GO
```

**Edit** - I've included the proof that my column does have the default value as `getdate()`, and the lLogin_Time is `(CONVERT([varchar](8),getdate(),(108)))`

[image]

**Injection Attack Note:** My code does not take any values from the user, all of this is calculated based off of program & database values, so I am not worried about an injection attack.

Comment: Could you add, to your code above, the schema definition of your table (IE. Sql Server Management Studio, right click on your table, select Script Table as ....)

Comment: @Steve Please see my edits, I have included what you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dropping the table and recreating it with the `datetime` in the one column. I'm  still not exactly sure why the server was defaulting to the start of the calendar, the only thing that seems logical is that VB was sending some sort of data to the columns and it was defaulting to the start instead of the current `datetime`. I've included my **new** table and it's code just incase anyone stumbles across the same issue in the future, though I doubt anyone will.

**The VB Code:**

```
        con.open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Account_Login_Logger (lAccount_ID) VALUES (@accountid)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountid", 91)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.close()
```

**The New Database Table:**

```
 USE [Atlas]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Account_Login_Logger]    Script Date: 27/01/2015 3:37:20 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account_Login_Logger](
    [lLogin_ID] [int] IDENTITY(10,1) NOT NULL,
    [lAccount_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [lDate_Time_Stamp] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_Login_Logger_lDate_Time_Stamp]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Account___0B8A2E93BF56F461] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [lLogin_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

My problem was **resolved** when I did this. Thank you for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think

```
INSERT INTO Account_Login_Log (lMember_ID, lAccount_ID, lLogin_Time, lLogin_Date)  VALUES (@memberID, @accountID, @logintime, @logindate)
```

Will use default values?

If you have default values set for the table do this instead:

```
INSERT INTO Account_Login_Log (lMember_ID, lAccount_ID) VALUES (@memberID, @accountID)
```

Because you are passing values to the insert statement it uses those instead of the default.

The reason why Query Manager is working differently is because when you use the C# platform it is converting what you are sending to the correct type (time and date) and then sending values to the server which are used.

Comment: Hi Hogan, I thought this myself. But Omitting the columns like you have said still results in the 'beginning of time' being set as the value.

Comment: In the "default value" field when you define your table, put getdate() to get the current time as the default value.

Comment: @Jeremy I know it looks like I haven't done that, but I have. And as I said, when I input the data using MS Management Studio it works. But for some reason doing it through vb is still resorting the default time and date columns to what appears to be their earliest available values.

Comment: an empty string is not nothing. you really have to not specify that column at all in your select list.

Comment: You have only two columns listed in your INSERT statement and it still defaults?

Comment: @Hogan Yes, it still resorts the default value to what appears to be the earliest available date and time. This is really frustrating now.

Comment: can I ask why you have a time field and a date field and not a datetime field.  datetime would work better and it is what GETDATE() returns.  To be honest I don't think I've ever set a default value for a date and a time, just for a datetime.

Comment: 1. Is your field a datetime (not a date?) 2. How are you observing this 00:00:00 data? In SQL Server Management Studio? You definitely need to _not_ supply the values as instructed in this post.

Comment: Firstly, I'm seeing this data in Management Studio, yes. And when I add records through management studio the values default to the CORRECT date/time - both using the SQL code AND the UI Elements. It's only when going through VB the dates go to the start of the calendar.

Comment: Secondly, I was always tuaght through College and Uni that all attributes  should contain atomic data. So I've simply implemented that discipline here, plus I plan on doing some sorting based on time.

Comment: I suggest you use SQL Profiler to work out what is really going on. It seems your VB code is adding explicit values without you telling it to. So fire up SQL Profiler and capture the SQL that is being run by your VB code. You can even capture it and run it directly in Management Studio to satisfy yourself that it's the same thing.

Comment: RE "Atomic Data" :  On SQL Server the datetime type is "atomic".  Date and Time types are much newer.  The timestamp data type has always been called datetime on MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Change you code to

```
    Dim cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Account_Login_Log " & _ 
                             "(lMember_ID, lAccount_ID) " & 
                             "VALUES (@memberID, @accountID)", cnn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", 32)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountID", 91)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

To `AddWithValue` you should pass the correct datatype. If the column expects a string you should pass a string, but if the column expects an int you pass an int,not a string. Moreover your INSERT doesn't need to pass values for the columns that have a default value. If you don't pass anything the default will be used. Finally the INSERT syntax requires that, if you don't pass parameters for all the field names you need to specify which columns are affected by your query. So you need to add the names of the two columns updated

[A interesting reading about AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Steve this is exactly the same as my answer.

Comment: No totally. You miss the field names in the query

Comment: hmmm... I thought they were optional if you are adding all needed fields in order

Comment: With the schema and the code provided I have tested in LinqPad and if you don't put the field names you get an exception. `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition`. With the correct field names in place the insertion works as expected and the default value kicks in for the missing values. By the way, the same query without the required field names fails also in SSMS with the same exception.